# Highlighting images on mouse enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 images which will be thumbnails for news articles. When the user moves their mouse over one of the images I want it to highlight. I have done this by placing a div of the same size over the image. I then tried to use JQuery to add a class to that div on mouse enter which would make it a slightly see through blue box as shown [here](https://gyazo.com/d5bbc87d4aee2b9250320db3313b4dd7).

HTML:

```
<div class="col-5 parent-center">
    <div id="news1" class="news-highlight"></div>
    <img src="images/news.jpg" class="news-image"/>
</div>
```

I know that in the JQuery I use .content as a reference to find the IDs of the news images faster. That does exist I just didn't copy in that far up the code because it would have resulted in a lot of code unrelated to my problem being pasted in.

CSS:

```
.news-image
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    border: solid 2px #14a0dc;
}

.news-highlight
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #14a0dc;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

JQuery:

```
function highlightNews(newsDiv)
{
    newsDiv.addClass('news-highlight');
}

function unhighlightNews(newsDiv)
{
    newsDiv.removeClass('news-highlight');
}

$(document).ready(function()
{   
    var $content = $('.content');
    var $news1 = $content.find('#news-1');
    var $news2 = $content.find('#news-2');
    var $news3 = $content.find('#news-3');
    var $news4 = $content.find('#news-4');

    function newsMouse(newsDiv)
    {
        newsDiv.on('mouseenter', highlightNews(newsDiv)).on('mouseleave', unhighlightNews(newsDiv));
    }

    newsMouse($news1);
    newsMouse($news2);
    newsMouse($news3);
    newsMouse($news4);
});
```

Now you're probably crying after seeing my JQuery, I'm trying to learn it on the fly so I don't really know what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You do not need the jQuery library for that. You can solve this using a pure simple CSS solution. Experiment with the `:hover` selector in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you should just need to change the colour of the div on top of your images when they are hovered on. This can easily be done with CSS. This should work:

```
.news-highlight
{
    background: rgba(51, 153, 255, 0);
}

.news-highlight:hover
{
    background: rgba(51, 153, 255, 0.5);
}
```

This will give the div a semi-transparent blue colour when the user hovers the cursor over it, and the image will show through.

You could also change the images to a greyscale at the same time, which may improve the effect.

EDIT: I should have also stated that you need to change the order of your html to this:

```
<div class="col-5 parent-center">
    <img src="images/news.jpg" class="news-image"/>
    <div id="news1" class="news-highlight"></div>
</div>
```

now the .news-highlight div will appear on top of your img.

Comment: A pure CSS solution like this should be preferred over one which involves Javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you make it with pure css without nothing of js?

```css
.news-image
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    border: solid 2px #14a0dc;
}

.news-image:hover
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #14a0dc;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-5 parent-center">
    <div id="news1" class="news-highlight"></div>
    <img src="images/news.jpg" class="news-image"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I thought using that method that it would highlight all of them whenever one was hovered on but apparently not. When I use this solution the colour doesn't change, is that because I'm applying the class to an <img />? If there isn't a way to make that work then I guess I can just put a div below it with the colour I want so that it shows through when the opacity is 0.6.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using pure `CSS`. basically highlighting is nothing but `box-shadow` or `border` on the hover.

```
.news-image:hover{
   border:solid 1px red;
}
```

Comment: why `border:solid 1px red;`?

Comment: just for example mate or say i like the red color.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **JQuery** to do something like this, one option is to use  [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
$('.news-image img').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('news-highlight');
});
```

```css
.news-image {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.news-image img{
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  width: 100%;
}

.news-highlight {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>

<div class="news-image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>

<div class="news-image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmsxpxzq/3/) how does hover effect work. Practice is the answer! jQuery not required for something this simple

```
.news-image
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    border: solid 2px #14a0dc;
}

.news-image:hover
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #14a0dc;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```